# ROS gpsd client Subscriber node (fix)

Tags: ros-lunar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to write subscriber node for ROS GPSD client which is publishing GPS coordinates on topic "/fix". I don't know exactly what would be the right code and what changes I have to make in CMakeList.txt and package.xml. Below is the code

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/NavSatStatus.h>  
#include <sensor_msgs/NavSatFix.h>
using namespace gps_common;
void callback(const sensor_msgs::NavSatFixConstPtr& fix) {
  if (fix->status.status == sensor_msgs::NavSatStatus::STATUS_NO_FIX) {
   ROS_INFO("No fix.");
   return;
 }

 if (fix->header.stamp == ros::Time(0)) {
   return;
}
printf("\n Latitude = %f and Logitude = %f ",fix->latitude, fix->logitude);  
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
 ros::init(argc, argv, "gps_collect");
 ros::NodeHandle node;
 ros::Subscriber fix_sub = node.subscribe("fix", 10, callback);
 ros::spin();
 return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286036/ros-gpsd-client-subscriber-node-(fix)/) by [Khan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34242/khan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-03-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-20**:
Have you gone through the [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials)? These cover the basics (subscribing, publishing, etc.) pretty well. Are you getting any errors that you can post? I can't imagine that this code compiles with `return` statements in a `void` function.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-20**:
Also, in one of your `include`s you're mixing `"` with `<`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-21**:
And just to make sure you've seen it: [gpsd_client](http://wiki.ros.org/gpsd_client). There's nothing wrong with wanting to learn how to do something yourself btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The code is fine and its working.  Thanks

---

Originally posted by [Khan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34242/khan/) with karma: 16 on 2018-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-26**:
To whom are you addressing this comment? @jayess was right: before you edited the code in your question text, there was mixup with `"` instead of `<` in one of your `#include` statements.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-26**:
If you've resolved your problem then please post the solution. If not, then please turn your answer into a comment.

**Comment by [Khan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34242/khan/) on 2018-03-26**:
If I am working on ROS and dont know to deal with syntax error then I would say I need to learn basic C/C++. Anyways I never had these brackets error, those were bcs of copy and paste. The problem here was I have to make few changes in CMakelist.txt and Package.xml file.

**Comment by [Khan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34242/khan/) on 2018-03-26**:
The above code is solution for capturing GPS Coordinates from fix(ros gpsgd client topic); Extra things you need is the right CMakelist.txt(add sensor_msgs) and Package.xml. Thanks and sorry for inconvenience